# Android ListView With Fragment View Not Created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm using a ListView in a fragment and I've set every necessary requirement as told by Android, my XML List Code below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#253453">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my code

```
   @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_frag, container, false);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    //ListView list = (ListView)android.findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListView list = getListView();

      trackItems = new ArrayList<TrackItem>();
      listAdapter = new TrackOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), trackItems);
      list.setAdapter(listAdapter); }
```

But, I still get this error

> 08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334): Process:
>   com.deliveryscience.track, PID: 30334 08-20 23:26:26.053:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30334): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view
>   not yet created 08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   com.deliveryscience.track.PendingActivity.onCreateView(PendingActivity.java:51)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
>   08-20 23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):  at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073) 08-20
>   23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919) 08-20
>   23:26:26.053: E/AndroidRuntime(30334):    at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)

Comment: post your whole `pending_frag` xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_frag, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    //ListView list = (ListView)android.findViewById(R.id.list);
    ListView list = getListView();

    trackItems = new ArrayList<TrackItem>();
    listAdapter = new TrackOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), trackItems);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter); 
}
```

You can't really manipulate the view until the views are created.

Comment: I thought as much too @CChi, it was after seeing your code i knew I was doing it wrong. Thanks Anyway